# Burn the [memo]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I recently encountered the [memo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memo) tag. The tag is really ambiguous, and I'd like to see it burn.

It currently has 110 questions, 2 followers, and no excerpt or wiki.

Some uses:

- Memo fields (long text fields) in databases (Access, DBase and more). However, for Access, the name *memo* is no longer used for such fields, and they're called *long text* instead ([source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-memo-data-type-is-now-called-long-text-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5))
- Short for memoization (should be tagged [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memoization))
- Short for computer memory (should be tagged [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory))
- The VCL TMemo class/control (should be tagged [tmemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmemo))
- Refund memos in Magento
- About memoranda, or sending reminders (off-topic for a tag)

I could walk through the burninate criteria, but the main problem with this tag is the ambiguity. Often enough, people using this tag don't use the appropriate tag too.

Comment: Suggestion for the title: **"Release the [memo]!"** (Don't know if you are following [US politics](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-42910377) though)

Comment: Preventing [ms-access] programmers from properly tagging their questions about memo columns is not reasonable.  Do not burn.  No doubt [delphi] community members will retag to [tmemo], etc, but there are always questions around that are not worth the effort and far too hard to delete.  Finding lousy questions is never difficult.

Comment: I guess the people who used the tag didn't get the [memo]

Comment: @HansPassant Access has ditched the _memo_ name for long text fields, and calls them _[long text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-memo-data-type-is-now-called-long-text-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5)_ instead. The tag name is not clear for that, nor does it have an excerpt stating it should be used for it. We could create a [long-text-field] tag or [long-text] tag if we want a tag to be used for such database fields.

Comment: News to me.  And apparently to a bunch of [ms-access] programmers.  This info belongs in your question.

Comment: @Hans I've edited my question to include it

Comment: What advantage would the deletion of the tag have?

Comment: Erase even the [memo]ry of this tag.

Comment: Send a [memo] to Trogdor.

Comment: @dit the main advantage would probably be that all the questions about tmemo would be in one place, a large percentage of this tags questions should be tagged tmemo. But people using this tag instead of the appropriate tag for any of the purposes I outlined would be helped if this tag was gone, since they would probably search and find the appropriate tag instead.

Comment: N.B. - re: Access - there's a [tag:longtext] tag, but it's all over the place. If an Access-specific Long Text tag is created, some of those will want to be adjusted, too.

Comment: I see the problem as a lack of expressiveness in the tag name, it should be bigger to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: With only 110 questions and 2 followers I would have thought it is too little used, or misused, to be of any concern.